# Activity in launchMode singleTask gets destroyed when started via TaskStackBuilder

Tags: android, android-activity, launchmode, taskstackbuilder

I have an activity **A**, declared in `Manifest` with `android:launchMode="singleTask"`
and another activity **B** that has no further attributes.

As far as I know, if there is already some task running activity A,
instead of creating a new instance, the current task is brought to front,
if I attempt to start activity A.

Now, I want to use the `TaskStackBuilder` to make a call which includes both activities.

Let's suppose I am on a Fragment within Activity **A** and call:

```
                TaskStackBuilder.create(context)
                    .addNextIntent(new Intent(context, A.class))
                    .addNextIntent(new Intent(context, B.class))
                    .startActivities();
```

I assume the current stack to become: **A** > **B** with **A** getting a call to `onNewIntent` and **B** with a new instance. Furthermore I expect Activity **A** to hold it's state.

But what happens is: I do *not* get a call to `onNewIntent`, but to `onDestroy` for Activity **A**. And if I go back from my newly created Activity **B**, `onCreate` is called for a new instance of Activity **A**. (They are not equal!).

Can anybody explain to me, why my Activity **A** is thrown away instead of doing nothing to it, but adding **B** to the stack? It is a shame, that I can't get my head around this problem by myself, but I can't see the obstacle here.

**Edit/Ps:** The `context` which I use for the StackBuilder can either be a views context or a Service context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, as nobody answered so far, I dived into the code from android in the meanwhile and discovered that **the StackBuilder itself is the issue**.

In detail..this part of code, which is present in the methods `startActivities()` and also in `getPendingIntent()`, causes my Activity **A** to get destroyed:

```
    public PendingIntent getPendingIntent(int requestCode, int flags, Bundle options) {
        if (mIntents.isEmpty()) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(
                    "No intents added to TaskStackBuilder; cannot getPendingIntent");
        }

        Intent[] intents = mIntents.toArray(new Intent[mIntents.size()]);
        intents[0] = new Intent(intents[0]).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK |
            IntentCompat.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK |
            IntentCompat.FLAG_ACTIVITY_TASK_ON_HOME);
        // Appropriate flags will be added by the call below.
        return IMPL.getPendingIntent(mSourceContext, intents, requestCode, flags, options);
    }
```

**It is this part:**

```
Intent[] intents = mIntents.toArray(new Intent[mIntents.size()]);
    intents[0] = new Intent(intents[0]).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK |
            IntentCompat.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK |
            IntentCompat.FLAG_ACTIVITY_TASK_ON_HOME);
```

My Activity **A** was in an existing Task. Although it has the *launchMode = "singleTask"* and should get reordered to front normally, the FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK is set to my first activity (which is **A**) and causes the existing task that would be associated with the **A** to be cleared before the activity is started.

That said, I won't use the StackBuilder in my special case now. 
I see several approaches to this: either use an empty Activity before
my first target Activity or building the stack myself inside of 
my Activity **A**'s `onCreate` / `onNewIntent`, by providing a Bundle
with a List of parcelables (intents) to start.

Comment: Yep, `TaskStackBuilder` always resets the task. This is why you should probably never use it. IMHO `TaskStackBuilder` is a big mistake and most people who use it (because it is recommended to use it) end up with more problems than it solves.

Comment: I totally share your opinion @DavidWasser

Comment: Please accept this answer so the question gets removed from the unanswered questions list.

Comment: Would already have. Due to the 2 days ineligable for accepting restriction, I forgot to accept it. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: I just discovered this and was glad to learn here that I'm not crazy. My first experiment will be to just override getIntents, since for whatever reason they made it public non final.